# Finger recogntion finding the convexity defects

Tags: python, opencv

So I'm trying to find fingers using convexityDefects(); however, I am getting a lot of false positives.  I thought I could fix this by going to the given convexity defect endpoint and within the contour near that area I could integrate to find the area and if it is small enough that could be determined an actual finger and not a false positive.  How would I go about doing so, any help would be great
Thanks!

Comment: If you solved this problem yourself, it would be very helpful if you could post your solution or a description of it.

Answer (score 0):

Well:

```
defects = cv2.convexityDefects(cnt,hull)
```

gives you a list of defects that are of the form:

```
[start_point,end_point,far_point,distance]
```

Using that you should be able to calculate the area of the triangles. However you will still likely see a number of false positives.

I've been asking a similar question here: [scipy signal find_peaks_cwt not finding the peaks accurately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25571260/scipy-signal-find-peaks-cwt-not-finding-the-peaks-accurately)