# scipy signal find_peaks_cwt not finding the peaks accurately?

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, image-segmentation

I've got a 1-D signal in which I'm trying to find the peaks. I'm looking to find them perfectly.

I'm currently doing:

```
import scipy.signal as signal
peaks = signal.find_peaks_cwt(data, np.arange(100,200))
```

The following is a graph with red spots which show the location of the peaks as found by `find_peaks_cwt()`.

[image: Signal + Peaks]

As you can see, the calculated peaks aren't accurate enough. The ones that are really important are the three on the right hand side.

My question: **How do I make this more accurate?**

UPDATE: Data is here: http://pastebin.com/KSBTRUmW

For some background, what I'm trying to do is locate the space in-between the fingers in an image. What is plotted is the x-coordinate of the contour around the hand. Cyan spots = peaks. If there is a more reliable/robust approach this, please leave a comment.

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly, the peak location accuracy is limited by the smallest number in the peak width parameter. So instead of `np.arange(100,200)`, perhaps `np.array([10, 50, 100, 200])` will give better results.

Comment: So, I just tried this, and it does seem to better, but it also finds lots of local bumps, rather than just the big ones, which makes the output full of false positives.

Comment: I encountered the similar problem and I want to ask how to determine the peak width parameter properly? I want to test your data yet I can't open the link(_the requested url could not be retrieved_)

Comment: Try the link again- I just checked it and it definitely works.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Solved, solution:

Filter data first:

```
  window = signal.general_gaussian(51, p=0.5, sig=20)
  filtered = signal.fftconvolve(window, data)
  filtered = (np.average(data) / np.average(filtered)) * filtered
  filtered = np.roll(filtered, -25)
```

Then use angrelextrema as per rapelpy's answer.

Result:

[image]

Comment: could you add the code for finding the peaks? I think the answer from rapelpy has been edited

Comment: cjm2671, please explain your answer in details, including the convolution with a laplacian kernel, scaling and rolling.

Comment: [Below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68473049/12131616) I posted a working function based on this answer.

Answer (score 17):

There is a much easier solution using this function:
https://gist.github.com/endolith/250860
which is an adaptation of http://billauer.co.il/peakdet.html

I've just tried with the data you provided and I got the result below. No need for pre-filtering...

Enjoy :-)

[image: peak detection]

Comment: Based on peakdet function I would expect to see noisy peaks appear. How is that you don't detect two peaks in the left-most, widest peak?

Comment: @aerijman: The amount of noise is controlled by the `delta` value (also called the peak/valley threshold). To achieve this result the `delta` is probably ~75. To see the noisy peaks you mentioned it needs to be significantly smaller (probably ~5).

Answer (score 5):

**Edited after getting the raw data.**

argelmax and arglextrma are out of the race.

The curve is very noisy, so you have to play with small peak width (as pv. mentioned) and the noise.

The best I found looks not very good.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as signal

peakidx = signal.find_peaks_cwt(y_array, np.arange(10,15), noise_perc=0.1)
print peakidx

[10, 100, 132, 187, 287, 351, 523, 597, 800, 1157, 1451, 1673, 1742, 1836]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this, unfortunately my results were rather worse than yours http://imgur.com/E4QbRXY. I could smooth the data first, although I feel this may distort the result.

Comment: Maybe this will work: signal.argrelmax(y_array, order=5)
Where order is how many points on each side to use for the comparison.

Comment: Unfortunately not; it produces less points, but seems to sacrifice good points for bad ones :(. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you upload your data somewhere?

Comment: Sure, data is here: http://pastebin.com/KSBTRUmW - thanks I really appreciate it.

Comment: Wow thanks for trying. I really appreciate the effort. At least it found the peaks, just lots of false positives. Do you think it's possible to filter the data first? I was thinking of perhaps convolving it with a triangle pulse and seeing what the output looked like.

Comment: OK I've solved it using a combination of methods! I used angrelextrema, but first convolved the signal with a laplacian window to smooth out the noise; then it was perfect. It's almost pixel perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Based on @cjm2671 answer, here is a working example for finding relative maxima and minima in a noisy signal:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter1d
from scipy import signal

data =np.array([5.14,5.22,5.16,4.82,4.46,4.36,4.4,4.35,4.13,3.83,3.59,3.51,3.46,3.27,3.08,3.03,2.95,2.96,2.98,3.02,3.09,3.14,3.06,2.84,2.68,2.72,2.92,3.23,3.44,3.5,3.28,3.34,3.73,3.97,4.26,4.48,4.5,5.06,6.02,6.68,7.09,7.58,8.6,9.85,10.7,11.3,11.3,11.6,12.3,12.6,12.8,12.8,12.5,12.4,12.2,12.2,12.3,11.9,11.2,10.6,10.3,10.3,10.,9.53,8.97,8.55,8.49,8.41,8.09,7.71,7.34,7.26,7.42,7.47,7.37,7.17,7.05,7.02,7.09,7.23,7.18,7.16,7.47,7.92,8.55,8.68,8.31,8.52,9.11,9.59,9.83,9.73,10.2,11.1,11.6,11.7,11.7,12.,12.6,13.1,13.3,13.2,13.,12.6,12.3,12.2,12.3,12.,11.6,11.1,10.9,10.9,10.7,10.3,9.83,9.64,9.63,9.37,8.88,8.39,8.14,8.12,7.92,7.48,7.06,6.87,6.87,6.63,6.17,5.71,5.45,5.45,5.34,5.05,4.78,4.57,4.47,4.37,4.16,3.95,3.88,3.83,3.69,3.64,3.57,3.5,3.51,3.33,3.14,3.09,3.06,3.12,3.11,2.94,2.83,2.76,2.74,2.77,2.75,2.73,2.72,2.59,2.47,2.53,2.54,2.63,2.76,2.78,2.75,2.69,2.54,2.42,2.58,2.79,2.83,2.78,2.71,2.77,2.88,2.97,2.97,2.9,2.92,3.16,3.29,3.28,3.49,3.97,4.32,4.49,4.82,5.08,5.48,6.03,6.52,6.72,7.16,8.18,9.52,10.9,12.1,12.6,12.9,13.3,13.3,13.6,13.9,13.9,13.6,13.3,13.2,13.2,12.8,12.,11.4,11.,10.9,10.4,9.54,8.83,8.57,8.61,8.24,7.54,6.82,6.46,6.43,6.26,5.78,5.29,5.,5.08,5.14,5.,4.84,4.56,4.38,4.52,4.84,5.33,5.52,5.56,5.82,6.54,7.27,7.74,7.64,8.14,8.96,9.7,10.2,10.2,10.5,11.3,12.,12.4,12.5,12.3,12.,11.8,11.8,11.9,11.6,11.,10.3,10.,9.98,9.6,8.87,8.16,7.76,7.74,7.54,7.03,6.54,6.25,6.26,6.09,5.66,5.31,5.08,5.19,5.4,5.38,5.38,5.22,4.95,4.9,5.02,5.28,5.44,5.93,6.77,7.63,8.48,8.89,8.97,9.49,10.3,10.8,11.,11.1,11.,11.,10.9,11.1,11.1,11.,10.7,10.5,10.4,10.3,10.4,10.3,10.2,10.1,10.2,10.4,10.4,10.5,10.7,10.8,11.,11.2,11.2,11.2,11.3,11.4,11.4,11.3,11.2,11.2,11.,10.7,10.4,10.3,10.3,10.2,9.9,9.62,9.47,9.46,9.35,9.12,8.82,8.48,8.41,8.61,8.83,8.77,8.48,8.26,8.39,8.84,9.2,9.31,9.18,9.11,9.49,9.99,10.3,10.5,10.4,10.2,10.,9.91,10.,9.88,9.47,9.,8.78,8.84,8.8,8.55,8.17,8.02,8.03,7.78,7.3,6.8,6.54,6.53,6.35,5.94,5.54,5.33,5.32,5.14,4.76,4.43,4.28,4.3,4.26,4.11,4.,3.89,3.81,3.68,3.48,3.35,3.36,3.47,3.57,3.55,3.43,3.29,3.19,3.2,3.17,3.21,3.33,3.37,3.33,3.37,3.38,3.26,3.34,3.62,3.86,3.92,3.83,3.69,4.2,4.78,5.03,5.13,5.07,5.4,6.,6.42,6.5,6.45,6.48,6.55,6.66,6.79,7.06,7.33,7.53,7.9,8.17,8.29,8.6,9.05,9.35,9.51,9.69,9.88,10.2,10.6,10.8,10.6,10.7,10.9,11.2,11.3,11.3,11.4,11.5,11.6,11.8,11.7,11.3,11.1,10.9,11.,11.2,11.1,10.6,10.3,10.1,10.2,10.,9.6,9.03,8.73,8.73,8.7,8.53,8.26,8.06,8.03,8.03,7.97,7.94,7.77,7.64,7.85,8.29,8.65,8.68,8.61,9.08,9.66,9.86,9.9,9.71,10.,10.9,11.4,11.6,11.8,11.8,11.9,11.9,12.,12.,11.7,11.3,10.9,10.8,10.7,10.4,9.79,9.18,8.89,8.87,8.55,7.92,7.29,6.99,6.98,6.73,6.18,5.65,5.35,5.35,5.22,4.89,4.53,4.28,4.2,4.05,3.83,3.67,3.61,3.61,3.48,3.27,3.05,2.9,2.93,2.99,2.99,2.98,2.94,2.88,2.89,2.92,2.86,2.97,3.,3.02,3.03,3.11,3.07,3.46,3.96,4.09,4.25,4.3,4.67,5.7,6.33,6.68,6.9,7.09,7.66,8.25,8.75,8.87,8.97,9.78,10.9,11.6,11.8,11.8,11.9,12.3,12.6,12.8,12.9,12.7,12.4,12.1,12.,12.,11.9,11.5,11.1,10.9,10.9,10.7,10.5,10.1,9.91,9.84,9.63,9.28,9.,8.86,8.95,8.87,8.61,8.29,7.99,7.95,7.96,7.92,7.87,7.77,7.78,7.9,7.73,7.51,7.43,7.6,8.07,8.62,9.06,9.24,9.13,9.14,9.46,9.76,9.8,9.78,9.73,9.82,10.2,10.6,10.8,10.8,10.9,11.,10.9,11.,11.,10.9,10.9,11.,10.9,10.8,10.5,10.2,10.2,10.2,9.94,9.51,9.08,8.88,8.88,8.62,8.13,7.64,7.37,7.37,7.23,6.91,6.6,6.41,6.42,6.29,5.94,5.57,5.43,5.46,5.4,5.17,4.95,4.84,4.87,4.9,4.69,4.4,4.24,4.26,4.35,4.34,4.19,3.96,3.97,4.42,5.03,5.34,5.15,4.73,4.86,5.35,5.88,6.35,6.52,6.81,7.26,7.62,7.66,8.01,8.91,10.,10.9,11.3,11.1,10.9,10.9,10.8,10.9,11.,10.7,10.2,9.68,9.43,9.42,9.17,8.66,8.13,7.83,7.81,7.62,7.21,6.77,6.48,6.44,6.31,6.06,5.72,5.47,5.45,5.42,5.31,5.23,5.22,5.3,5.32,5.16,4.96,4.82,4.73,4.9,4.95,4.91,4.92,5.41,6.04,6.34,6.8,7.08,7.26,7.95,8.57,8.78,8.95,9.06,9.14,9.2,9.33,9.53,9.65,9.69,9.53,9.18,9.02,9.,8.82,8.42,8.05,7.85,7.84,7.79,7.58,7.28,7.09,7.07,6.94,6.68,6.35,6.09,6.2,6.27,6.24,6.16,5.91,5.86,6.02,6.19,6.45,6.92,7.35,7.82,8.4,8.87,9.,9.09,9.61,9.99,10.4,10.8,10.7,10.7,11.1,11.4,11.5,11.5,11.3,11.3,11.4,11.7,11.8,11.5,11.,10.5,10.4,10.3,9.94,9.23,8.52,8.16,8.15,7.86,7.23,6.59,6.26,6.25,6.04,5.55,5.06,4.81,4.78,4.62,4.28,3.98,3.84,3.92,3.93,3.68,3.46,3.31,3.16,3.11,3.18,3.19,3.14,3.28,3.3,3.16,3.19,3.04,3.07,3.59,3.83,3.82,3.95,4.06,4.71,5.39,5.89,6.06,6.08,6.45,6.97,7.57,8.1,8.25,8.55,8.92,9.09,9.2,9.32,9.36,9.45,9.65,9.73,9.7,9.82,9.94,9.92,9.97,9.93,9.78,9.63,9.48,9.49,9.48,9.2,8.81,8.34,8.,8.06,7.98,7.63,7.47,7.37,7.24,7.2,7.05,6.93,6.83,6.59,6.44,6.42,6.33,6.18,6.37,6.29,6.1,6.34,6.57,6.54,6.77,7.21,7.58,7.86,8.11,8.57,9.07,9.45,9.67,9.68,9.87,10.2,10.4,10.4,10.4,10.4,10.4,10.5,10.6,10.7,10.4,9.98,9.58,9.45,9.51,9.44,9.09,8.68,8.46,8.36,8.17,7.88,7.55,7.34,7.3,7.17,6.97,6.88,6.69,6.69,6.77,6.77,6.81,6.67,6.5,6.57,6.99,7.4,7.59,7.8,8.45,9.47,10.4,10.8,10.9,10.9,11.,11.4,11.8,12.,11.9,11.4,10.9,10.8,10.8,10.5,9.76,8.99,8.59,8.58,8.43,8.05,7.61,7.26,7.16,6.99,6.58,6.15,5.98,5.93,5.71,5.48,5.22,5.06,5.08,4.95,4.78,4.62,4.45,4.48,4.65,4.66,4.69])

dataFiltered = gaussian_filter1d(data, sigma=5)
tMax = signal.argrelmax(dataFiltered)[0]
tMin = signal.argrelmin(dataFiltered)[0]

plt.plot(data, label = 'raw')
plt.plot(dataFiltered, label = 'filtered')
plt.plot(tMax, dataFiltered[tMax], 'o', mfc= 'none', label = 'max')
plt.plot(tMin, dataFiltered[tMin], 'o', mfc= 'none', label = 'min')
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('fig.png', dpi = 300)
```

The Gaussian filter already implements the convolution with Gaussian windows. We just have to give it the standard deviation of the window as a parameter.

[image]

In this case, this approach works much better than using [`signal.find_peaks_cwt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt.html).