# How to find first local maximum for every group?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a Pandas data frame as follows:

```
Test Parameter Value

X1     0        0.033285423511615113
X1     1        0.78790279861666179
X1     2        0.79136989638378297
X1     3        0.80063190842016707
X1     4        0.7884653622402551
X1     5        0.78561849214309198...
...
X1     22       22: 0.82241991278171311...
...
X2 ...
```

I'd like to get the row with Parameter value 3. That is the row with the last increasing value before the first drop. Notice that later on we might have higher values (eg row 22). Essentially, I'm trying to get the "last" number before the "first" decrease value.

Also note that there are multiple Tests, so I probably need to do something like:

```
myDF.groupby("Test").Something
```

Comment: Do you want just the last peak or all such peaks?

Comment: I misunderstood the question I think

Comment: Do you want the first local maxima?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `np.diff`, it will naturally reduce the length of array by one and when I use `np.flatnonzero` it will identify the ordinal positions prior.

```
df.iloc[[np.flatnonzero(np.diff(df.Value) < 0)[0]]]

  Test  Parameter     Value
3   X1          3  0.800632
```

---

**Note:**
We can speed this up by accessing the underlying numpy array

```
df.iloc[[np.flatnonzero(np.diff(df.Value.values) < 0)[0]]]
```

---

**Explanation**

Get differences

```
np.diff(df.Value)

array([ 0.754618,  0.003467,  0.009262, -0.012167, -0.002847,  0.036802])
```

Find where differences are negative

```
np.flatnonzero(np.diff(df.Value) < 0)

array([3, 4])
```

I want the first one

```
np.flatnonzero(np.diff(df.Value) < 0)[0]

3
```

Use double brackets in an `iloc`

```
df.iloc[[3]]

  Test  Parameter     Value
3   X1          3  0.800632
```

---

**The Group By Looks Like**

```
f = lambda d: d.iloc[[np.flatnonzero(np.diff(d.Value.values) < 0)[0]]]
df.groupby('Test').apply(f)

       Test  Parameter     Value
Test                            
X1   3   X1          3  0.800632
```

Comment: Awesome super sir. you can also add the groupby method na. Op wants that for multiple test cases

Comment: I mean `df.groupby('Test',as_index=False).apply(lambda x : x.iloc[np.flatnonzero(np.diff(x.Value) < 0)[0]])`. You might have better

Answer (score 7):

Coldspeed nearly has it, to get only the first group you can use cumprod, or similar e.g.

```
In [11]: df[((df.Value.diff().fillna(1) > 0).cumprod()) == 1].tail(1)
Out[11]:
  Test  Parameter     Value
3   X1          3  0.800632
```

The trick being:

```
In [12]: (df.Value.diff().fillna(1) > 0)
Out[12]:
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
6     True
Name: Value, dtype: bool

In [13]: (df.Value.diff().fillna(1) > 0).cumprod()
Out[13]:
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    0
5    0
6    0
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```

---

Note: My df is this:

```
In [21]: df
Out[21]:
  Test  Parameter     Value
0   X1          0  0.033285
1   X1          1  0.787903
2   X1          2  0.791370
3   X1          3  0.800632
4   X1          4  0.788465
5   X1          5  0.785618
6   X1         22  0.822420
```

Comment: There's definitely a nicer way to do this, but I don't recall it.

Comment: Cumprod is a very nice trick that has eluded me for ever, gotta remember that. +1'd

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ you can do a similar trick with cumsum if you can make the changes (rows that "change") True... then you can groupby the result for example, I think that's what I was thinking of/trying to recall.

Comment: @AndyHayden: I think this is it -- one question though, if there are multiple tests, how do I groupBy test. Would it be: df[((df.groupby("Test"). Value.diff().fillna(1) > 0).cumprod()) == 1].tail(1)

Answer (score 3):

Use `diff` + `tail`:

```
df    
  Test  Parameter     Value
0   X1          0  0.033285
1   X1          1  0.787903
2   X1          2  0.791370
3   X1          3  0.800632
4   X1          4  0.788465
5   X1          5  0.785618

df[df.Value.diff().gt(0)].tail(1)    
  Test  Parameter     Value
3   X1          3  0.800632
```

This will retrieve the *last* local minima. If you want the *first* local minima, refer to [Andy Hayden's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46870795/4909087) involving `cumprod`.

---

If you're doing this in a `groupby` operation, it'd be something like (borrowing from Andy):

```
df.groupby('Test', group_keys=False)\
      .apply(lambda x: x[((x.Value.diff().fillna(1) > 0).cumprod()) == 1].tail(1))
```

Comment: No no no not the one. I used the same thing with shift but it has to be every increasing value

Comment: @Bharathshetty yeah, I think tail should handle that. Anyway, I'll wait for OP.

Comment: There had to be two rows 3 and 22

Comment: @Bharathshetty `Essentially, I'm trying to get the "last" number before the "first" decrease value.` So just one.

Comment: @Bharathshetty and cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I think OP wants the first local maxima

Answer (score 3):

I think `max` can do it ...

```
df.sort_values('Value', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['Test'])
Out[226]: 
  Test  Parameter     Value
3   X1          3  0.800632
```

Or

```
df[df['Value'] == df.groupby(['Test'])['Value'].transform(max)]
Out[227]: 
  Test  Parameter     Value
3   X1          3  0.800632
```

Seems this is what your need ...anyway using ugly way to correct my old post~ .

```
df1=df.loc[(df.Value.diff().fillna(1) > 0).nonzero()[0]].reset_index()
df1.groupby(df1['index'].diff().ne(1).cumsum()).last().iloc[0,]
Out[289]: 
index               3
Test               X1
Parameter           3
Value        0.800632
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

For `groupby`

```
l=[]
for _,dfs in df.groupby('Test'):
    df1 = dfs.loc[(dfs.Value.diff().fillna(1) > 0).nonzero()[0]].reset_index()
    l.append(df1.groupby(df1['index'].diff().ne(1).cumsum()).last().iloc[0,].to_frame().T)


pd.concat(l,axis=0)
```

Comment: Nice one. +1 Max should find the global maxima.

Comment: I agree. I meant to say that max is a very sensible solution!

Comment: I think 22 has the same parameter test, so don't see how this can work :/
Maybe I misunderstand OPs question !

Comment: `df.iloc[df.groupby('Test')['Value'].idxmax()]`?

Comment: @Zero nice improvement:-)

Comment: @AndyHayden I think you are right , But All I know is about `cumprod` and `scipy`(You and Bh already posted), so I made a very ugly way to achieve this ...

Answer (score 3):

Also from scipy [argrelextrema](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.argrelextrema.html) we can do (From [finding local maximas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35282456/find-local-maximums-in-numpy-array))

```
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
maxInd = argrelextrema(df['Value'].values, np.greater)
df.iloc[maxInd[0][:1]]
```

```
Test  Parameter     Value
3   X1          3  0.800632
```

A groupby solution if you have a dataframe  i.e

```
 Test  Parameter     Value
0   X1          0  0.033285
1   X1          1  0.787903
2   X1          2  0.791370
3   X1          3  0.800632
4   X1          4  0.788465
5   X2          5  0.785618
6   X2         22  0.822420
7   X2          5  0.785618
```

```
def get_maxima(x):
    return x.iloc[argrelextrema(x['Value'].values,np.greater)[0][:1]]

df.groupby('Test').apply(get_maxima)
```

Output :

```
    Test  Parameter     Value
0 3   X1          3  0.800632
1 6   X2         22  0.822420
```

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.argrelextrema.html

Comment: I think this needs to be `df.iloc[maxInd[0][:1]]`, but very neat!

Comment: Also added a groupby approach for multiple maximas . Thank you sir