# Finding peaks in noisy data with find_peaks_cwt

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to find the peaks in some very noisy data such as this: [image]

Without understanding the terminology very well, I'm defining the peaks as narrow (width<30) and more than 100000 higher than the nearby area.

I'm trying to use scipy's find_peaks_cwt but the documentation is pretty unclear to me. I tried `find_peaks_cwt(my_data, np.arange(1,30))` but it returned a huge number of peaks. Then I tried adding the `noise_perc=60` argument but this didn't really fix the problem. I've also tried playing around with the other parameters but I don't really understand what a 'ridge line' is.

What should I be doing differently? Is `widths=np.arange(1,30)` setting my width requirement like I think it is? How do I specify a height requirement?

Comment: An alternative approach that worked better for me was to filter manually the signal first convoluting it with a Gaussian window and then search for the maxima (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25666951/12131616)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot depends on what your data actually mean (or what you think they ought to mean). Here's an example with synthetic data:

```
from scipy.signal import find_peaks_cwt
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, ylim
from numpy import *
N = 2000
x = arange(N)
pwid = 200.
zideal = sinc(x/pwid - 2)**2 # Vaguely similar to yours
z = zideal * random.randn(N)**2 # adding noise
plot(x, zideal, lw=4)
ylim(0, 1)
zf = find_peaks_cwt(z, pwid/4+zeros(N))
plot(x[zf], zideal[zf], '*', ms=20, color='green')
# Create averaging zones around peaks
xlow = maximum(array(zf) - pwid/2, 0)
xhigh = minimum(array(zf) + pwid/2, x.max())
zguess = 0*xlow # allocate space
for ii in range(len(zf)):
   zguess[ii] = z[xlow[ii]:xhigh[ii]].mean()
plot(x[zf], zguess, 'o', ms=10, color='red')
```

`pwidth` scales the width of the peaks in the `sinc()` function. In the call to `find_peaks_cwt()`, using larger values for `widths` produces fewer peaks (lower density of peaks). The best result seems to be scaling values in `widths` to approximately half-width at half-max (HWHM) of the peaks.

`find_peaks_cwt()` does a pretty respectable job of finding the peaks from the ideal data. Summing around the values is a way to guess at the peak values. If you're summing spectral power, you should probably sum all the values in between rather than a fixed interval like I did for this quick-and-dirty demo.

[image: ploted as in example]

I find the function especially impressive in the way it finds smaller peaks in the presence of much larger ones.

Comment: It seems like the primary feature differentiating your peak search is `pwid/4+zeros(N)`. Can you explain how you selected that? I don't understand either how you picked the magnitude or that it should be an array the same length as the number of points.

Comment: From the documentation, widths is: "1-D array of widths to use for calculating the CWT matrix. In general, this range should cover the expected width of peaks of interest." In this case, I scaled the interval in sinc() to pwid. The "widths" array is one-sided width, so I scaled it to approximate the HWHM of the peaks.